# Autohotkey v2.0.2 Performance Issue on changing keys

Tags: autohotkey, colemak

I'm a colemak user, I use ahk to change keys from qwerty layout into colemak. (f -> t, j -> n, ..., etc)

Recently I upgraded ahk from v1.1 to v2.0.2, However, I found that the v2 version had some performance issues that I had never encountered on the v1 version.

When I type, sometime some keys don't transformed as expected.

For example, when I enter t and n alternately (i.e., the hardware f and j keys), sometimes I get f or j (not converted correctly). I have reduced my script to only these lines and can still reproduce the problem (But the simpler the script, the faster I need to type to reproduce it):

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0
f::t
j::n
```

Here is the output: `nnntntntjtjtnntntntnntnttntntnntntnntnntntntnfntnntntjtnntntntntntnnfjtj`, as you can see, some `f` and `j` in the text.

I've tested in my 3 computers, this problem can be reproduced on all these machines.

1. Thinkpad T14 gen1 (amd), windows 11
2. diy pc with i5-7500, windows 10
3. diy pc with i5-13600kf, windows 11